# HTML: How to correctly format 4 elements on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I have a page which should display 4 elements at a time: 
Name1: value     Name2: value

I have used CSS to accomplish this and it works pretty well but if value is extremely long, it should continue on the next line like so:

```
Name1:  sdlhjbdsl      Name2: value
        aldlhsdfidshf
        sifhflkgh
Name3:  hhlsdifsdlfh   Name4: sdhsdlkfbsdljkbs
                              aiuhdwdifnb
                              s;kkvnsdfk;vn
```

but it actually happens like this:

```
Name1:  sdlhjbdsl      
        aldlhsdfidshf
        sifhflkgh
                       Name2: sdhsdlkfbsdljkbs
                              aiuhdwdifnb
                              s;kkvnsdfk;vn
```

How can I best accomplish the first example? This is my CSS thus far:

```
#printable_block1
{ 

    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS","Arial","Sans-Serif";
            font-size: 12px;
    display:inline;
            position:absolute;
    margin-left: 12px; 
    max-width:23%; 
}
#printable_block1_value 
{
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS","Arial","Sans-Serif";
            font-size: 12px;
    display:block;
            position:relative;
    margin-left: 25%; 
    max-width:30%; 
}
#printable_block2 
{
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS","Arial","Sans-Serif";
            font-size: 12px;
    display:inline;
            position:absolute;
    margin-left: 50%; 
    max-width:24%;
}
#printable_block2_value 
{ 
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS","Arial","Sans-Serif";
            font-size: 12px;
    display:block;
            position:relative;
    margin-left: 75%; 
    max-width:25%;
}
```

Then this is my HTML:

```
<div id="block_container_3_blocks"> 
    <div id="printable_block1">
        <span>
           Name1:
       </span></div>
            <div id="printable_block1_value">
       <span>
           value1
       </span></div>
    <div id="printable_block2">
        <span>Name2:</span></div>
    <div id="printable_block2_value">
        <span>
           value2
        </span></div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is very "haxy", but you can add `top:0` to re-align your blocks.

Instead of all this, consider just using:

```
#block_container_3_blocks {font-size:0}
#block_container_3_blocks>div {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:25%; /* adjust to allow different numbers of blocks */
    font-size:12pt; /* whatever your default is */
}
```

The "font-size:0" part is to make sure any spaces between your elements don't mess up the layout.

Comment: this approach works like a charm, thank you! PS my first real encounter with CSS, thanks for not busting my balls :P

Comment: Now, when I use margin-left, it takes the margin starting from the element before the one I'm using, is there a way to make sure margin-left is measured from the left-side of the page?

Comment: You probably don't want that - the width of the element will offset the next element appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another way like

```css
.mainBlocks
 {
  clear: both;
 }
 .divClass{
  width:25%;
  float:left;
  font-family: "Arial Unicode MS","Arial","Sans-Serif";
  font-size: 12px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="mainBlocks">
   <div class="divClass">
    <span> Name1: </span>
   </div>
   <div  class="divClass">
    <span> value1 </span>
   </div>
   <div class="divClass">
    <span>Name2:</span>
   </div>
   <div  class="divClass">
    <span> value2 </span>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div class="mainBlocks">
   <div  class="divClass">
    <span> Name1: </span>
   </div>
   <div  class="divClass">
    <span> value1 </span>
   </div>
   <div  class="divClass">
    <span>Name2:</span>
   </div>
   <div  class="divClass">
    <span> value2 </span>
   </div>
  </div>
```